# Abort and rerun command

Tags: command-line, cmd

In the command line, I currently have to press `Ctrl-C` to abort the running task and then press the `up-arrow` key to select the previous command and then press `Enter` to run it again. It's getting tedious, is there a way to "abort and rerun" without doing all that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop:

```
:start
ping localhost -t
goto :start
```

Pressing `ctrl + c` on this prompts `Terminate Batch Job Y/N` which you can dismiss with another `ctrl + c`. So it's just a double press.